# How to prove that $\mathbb R^3$ has an infinite amount of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is clear that every two dimensional plane in $\mathbb R^3$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Since there are infinitely many two dimensional planes in $\mathbb R^3$, it follows that there are infinitely many subspaces in $\mathbb R^3$.

I think that this proof is not formal enough because it fails at showing that there are infinitely many two dimensional planes in $\mathbb R^3$. How to show this? If this can be shown would the proof be complete?

Informally, one could say that any two vectors $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^3 $$ that are non-scalar multiples of each other and start at the origin can form a two dimensional plane in $\mathbb R^3$. Since there are infinitely many possibilities for the entries of these vectors then there are infinitely many possible two dimensional planes in $\mathbb R^3$.

I don't know if this is the right way to go in order to prove that $\mathbb R^3$ has an infinite amount of subspaces. Is there a simpler way to proof this that relies only on basic notions of linear algebra?

Comment: the problem with your argument is that two vectors do not correspond to one unique subspace. i.e. for each two dimensional subspace there are several vector-pairs spanning it

Comment: It might be easier to consider one-dimensional subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec{v}$ be any unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the set $\{t\textbf{v}:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates a one-dimensional vector space. Its complement is a 2-dimensional subspace. There are thus infinitely many of both.

Answer (score 4):

There is no harm in being more specific: For each $0 \leq t < 2\pi$, consider the plane spanned by
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \cos t \\ \sin t \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$
You can show that none of these planes are equal. There are of course more planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ than these, but these planes are infinitely many nonetheless.